# How to change value of different cell based on dropdown option selected in another cell in Mui datagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I have created Mui [datagrid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/tree-data/) table with tree data. I have one column in which I have rendered html select tag with option fetched from `GridRowsProp` using custom renderCell function..

What I want. I have two elements in rows data `experience` and `salary` as array. I am using `experience` array data to feed as option to select tag which will be rendered in each cell of Experience column.

[image: Like this]

So let's say I choose "One" from the select dropdown. It appears at index 0. I want to take the same index value out of the `salary` array and put it in the appropriate column cell. i.e in same row

here is my rows data sample

```js
const rows: GridRowsProp = [
  {
    hierarchy: ["Sarah"],
    jobTitle: "Head of Human Resources",
    recruitmentDate: new Date(2020, 8, 12),
    experience: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
    salary: [12, 32, 42, 54],
    id: 0
  },
  {
    hierarchy: ["Thomas"],
    jobTitle: "Head of Sales",
    recruitmentDate: new Date(2017, 3, 4),
    experience: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
    salary: [12, 32, 42, 54],
    id: 1
  },
  {
    hierarchy: ["Mary", "Linda", "William"],
    jobTitle: "Back-end developer",
    recruitmentDate: new Date(2018, 4, 19),
    experience: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
    salary: [12, 32, 42, 54],
    id: 14
  }
];
```

here is how am creating column

```js
const columns: GridColumns = [
  { field: "jobTitle", headerName: "Job Title", width: 200 },
  {
    field: "recruitmentDate",
    headerName: "Recruitment Date",
    type: "date",
    width: 150
  },
  {
    field: "experience",
    headerName: "Experience",
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return <Dropdown props={params} />;
    }
  },

  {
    field: "salary",
    headerName: "Salary",
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      const salaryArr = params.row.salary as number[];
      return salaryArr[0];
    }
  }
];
```

and here is my Dropdown function

```js
function Dropdown(params) {
  if (params.props.value && params.props.value.length > 0) {
    return (
      <select
      // onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {params.props.value.map((x, y) => (
          <option key={y}>{x}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

I have created a basic application with tree data. Here is link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-chebyshev-uglgvw?file=/demo.tsx)  where I have added all things Which I mentioned above